# Are the cohomology groups of the real projective plane the same as those of a half of it?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Are the cohomology groups of the real projective plane the same as those if I take the upper hemisphere of it only?

Comment: if we consider the definition that makes the projective plane represented by a sphere @SassatelliGiulio

Comment: Brain - if my guess about what you mean is correct, notice that the image of the upper hemisphere is the image of the entire sphere, so, you're asking if the cohomology of the same space is the same!

Comment: @FShrike  like here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDtwgpQfJlc&t=199s

Comment: @FShrike yes if the cohomology of the upper hemisphere of the projective plane is the same as the cohomology of the whole sphere

Comment: @Brain Uh, the upper hemisphere *is* the sphere. When you project it down into the projective plane

Comment: ok, so they are the same? @FShrike

Answer (score 2):

The projective plane does not have "hemispheres." There are at least two standard ways to construct the projective plane from the sphere: (1) as the quotient space of $S^2$ where you identify $(x,y,z) \in S^2$ with $(-x,-y,-z)$, and (2) as the quotient space of the upper hemisphere of points $(x,y,z)$ with $z \geq 0$ where you identify $(x,y,0)$ with $(-x,-y,0)$. Maybe you mean construction (2)? Of course (1) and (2) give exactly the same topological space, the real projective plane, so of course you get the same cohomology either way.